# Get Total requests in a period of time

Tags: prometheus, promql

I need to show, in Grafana, a panel with the number of requests in the period of time selected in the upper right corner.

For this I need to solve 2 issues here, I will ask the prometheus question here and the Grafana question in another link.

If I have a Counter `http_requests_total`, How can I build a query to get **an integer** with the total number of requests during a period of time (for example:24hs)?

Comment: Note that Prometheus may return fractional value from `increase()` function on a time series with integer values. It may also miss some values on slowly increasing time series. Both issues are documented at https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746 . If you need accurate integer values from `increase()` function, then take a look at [MetricsQL](https://victoriametrics.github.io/MetricsQL.html).

Answer (score 269, accepted):

What you need is the [increase()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase) function, that will calculate the difference between the counter values at the start and at the end of the specified time interval. It also correctly handles counter resets during that time period (if any).

```
increase(http_requests_total[24h])
```

If you have multiple counters `http_requests_total` (e.g. from multiple instances) and you need to get the cumulative count of requests, use the [sum()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators) operator:

```
sum(increase(http_requests_total[24h]))
```

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47173828/8868289) to that part of the question about using Grafana's time range selection in queries.

Comment: What if period is not last 24h, but from fist date&time and second date&time?

Comment: @Cherry, You can use an offset, e.g. `increase(http_requests_total[5h] offset 1d)` or `increase(http_requests_total[357s] offset 123m)`. This way you specify the width of the period you interested in and how far in the past this period is. But this is definitely NOT a convenient way. Maybe somebody else can suggest a more practical solution to your question. [@donotreply's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54776593/8868289) looks like what you ask for, but seems to be applicable only when using Graphana.

Comment: Actually on server restart prometheus values get reset to 0, so the graph suddenly drops, if we see the increase of 24 hr, it comes inaccurate as it is the difference of the first and last value , any better approach to this ?

Comment: @somyabhargava I had the exact problem - I found the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55928079/grafana-single-stat-after-big-counter-reset . So in this case it would be `sum(increase(http_requests_total[100y]))`

Comment: But `sum(increase(http_requests_total[100y]))` will get you the total value over the whole lifetime of the counter and not just the selected time interval

Comment: Yes exactly what @JellyFilledNuts said, this will be a whole lifetime counter

Comment: What about count of bucket elements? If I run job_timer_myjob_bucket{le="+Inf"} it returns number of items in the bucket e.g. 100. Now I would like to get the same count for specified interval e.g. for the previous day. If I use increase(job_timer_myjob_bucket{le="+Inf"}[1h]) it return me not integer - e.g. 55.8 is returned.

Answer (score 68):

SO won't let me comment on Yoory's answer so I have to make a new one...

In Grafana 5.3, they introduced [`$__range`](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#__range) for Prometheus that's easier to use:

```
sum(rate(http_requests_total[$__range]))
```

> This variable represents the range for the current dashboard. It is calculated by to - from

http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/prometheus/

Comment: note: for me, $__range does work, but grafana does not show it as an available variable in its helper tooltip/popup. go hardcore and type it out.

Answer (score 28):

As per [increase() documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase), it is not aggregation operator.
Thus, it will give wrong answer. (See note.)

You should use [sum_over_time()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) function which aggregates over time interval.

```
sum_over_time(http_requests_total[24h])
```

If you have multiple counters, use sum() operator:

```
sum(sum_over_time(http_requests_total[24h]))
```

Note:
I have 5 datapoints which has values: 847, 870, 836, 802, 836. (updated every minute)

```
increase(http_requests_total[5m]) returns 2118.75 

sum_over_time(http_requests_total[5m]) returns 4191
```

Comment: sum_over_time shouldn't be used directly on counters, use after rate.

Comment: When I use `sum(sum_over_time(http_requests_total[$__interval]))` I am still seeing drops in the graph while instead it should be monotonously increasing.

Comment: The data points are not monotonically increasing.  Is the counter resetting every minute and you're collecting every minute?  Are you performing a push method of getting data into prometheus?  This would explain why sum_over_time works for you. 

For others who's data points would be scraped a reset cannot happen every minute, so you would find counters that look like this: 847, 1690, 2412, 3245, 4023.  In this case the increase function should work better.

Answer (score 20):

```
http_requests_total - http_requests_total offset $__interval > 0
```

This builds off another answer and comment that works and handles restart situations.

The offset keeps the value always as an integer and does not try to perform interpolation like the `increase` and `rate` functions.

The `> 0` filter at the end will ignore all of the negative values that could be captured due to a restart.

The end result is the accurate total number of requests over time if you choose to chose the total value in the legend.

Comment: All the answers using increase() didn't work across all dashboard ranges, this one does!

Answer (score 12):

**Solution**: In order to calculate sum of https counters on prometheus grafana you should use `increase` method and set **generic Time Range** `$interval` in order to sum and calculate all http requests counters.

```
increase(http_requests_total[$interval])
```

According to [Prometheus Reference](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase):

> `increase()`
>   **increase(v range-vector)** calculates the increase in the time series in the range vector. Breaks in monotonicity (such as counter resets due to target restarts) are automatically adjusted for. The increase is extrapolated to cover the full time range as specified in the range vector selector, so that it is possible to get a non-integer result even if a counter increases only by integer increments.
>
> The following example expression returns the number of HTTP requests
>   as measured over the last 5 minutes, per time series in the range
>   vector:
>
> `increase(http_requests_total{job="api-server"}[5m])` increase should
>   only be used with counters. It is syntactic sugar for rate(v)
>   multiplied by the number of seconds under the specified time range
>   window, and should be used primarily for human readability. Use rate
>   in recording rules so that increases are tracked consistently on a
>   per-second basis.

**P.S**

1. You should set the correct **Quick range** on Grafana for setting the right time frame you choose (that straight rendered to `$interval` variable) In addition I suggest to set on the **Graph visualisation**  the right resolution and Min time interval ( in your case it's per day -> `1d`)

2.In order to sum all amount of requests just perform sum function

```
sum(increase(http_requests_total[$interval]))
```

Comment: I used `sum(increase(http_requests_total[$interval]))` query and visualized it in Grafana bar chart. I would expect that the far right bar would display today's data. However, it displays yesterday's data. Moreover, the date below the bar is incorrect, it is one day in the future (it displays `7-Apr-2022` although yesterday was `6-Apr-2022`).

Answer (score 4):

To get the exact count for the last 24 for hours I have created the following query:

```
max_over_time(http_requests_total[6s])- min_over_time(http_requests_total[24h])
```

Note: works for me :)

Comment: This will give you wrong results if `http_requests_total` has been reset during those 24 hours.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this in the modern version of Grafana is to set the Calculation field of the Value options section to "Difference" reduce function:

[image]

The query is your `http_requests_total` data without any aggregation.

Comment: thx, this is the most accurate answers

Comment: ..but this aproach won't be restart proof, that's the disadvantage

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that all the previous answers have misinterpreted the questions, which is to get a count from t0 to t1, where the value at t0 should be 0.

For this one can use the @ modifier as per the documentation https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#modifier:

```
http_requests_total - http_requests_total @ start()
```

Comment: I think this one will not give the correct result in case of counter reset.

Comment: @DuyTran why would you make a counter reset? isn't the counter should always start counting from 0 everytime you pick t0 and t1 ?

Comment: @YosraMH it resets in case of your app restarted or u set the counter to 0 in purpose. Normally, t0->0, t10->10 then above func works. In case of counter reset at t10, t10->0. The increase is now 0. right?

Answer (score 2):

`sum(increase(http_requests_total[$__range]))` worked for me. $__range is grafana variable which reflects time range selected in top right of grafana.

It is highly recommended to use increase to automatically adjust counter for resets.

Increase results in fractional values due to extrapollation at boundaries as well. Rounding functions with the query also worked for me.

```
round(sum(increase(http_requests_total[$__range])))
```

or

Since you are using grafana you can set decimals to 0 in standard options. (in grafana 9.1.8 this is not working, its bug). So I have set this in panel json as below.

```
  "fieldConfig": {
    "defaults": {
      "mappings": [],
      "thresholds": {
        "mode": "absolute",
        "steps": [
          {
            "value": null,
            "color": "green"
          },
          {
            "value": 80,
            "color": "red"
          }
        ]
      },
      "color": {
        "mode": "thresholds"
      },
      "decimals": 0,
      "unit": "none"
    },
    "overrides": []
  }
```

Note:  These queries are tried with grafana stat panel. (grafana version 9.1.8)

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I have the confusion too, and I got some solutions for it, but all of them are not all work perfectly.

---

solution 1:

```
    sum(increase(your_point))[$__interval]
```

This one will cause some different value with same statement, and also will cause the zero-value (actually not zero).

---

Solution 2:

```
    max_over_time(your_point[$__range])- min_over_time(your_point[$__range])
```

```
    your_point[$__range] -  your_point offset $__range
```

Both of this have potentially bug (value reset), and only can get the value in [sometime-now], cannot get the answer in anytime period.

---

Solution 3:

```
    sum_over_time(your_point)[$__range]
```

This solution will take much time to change your metrics (reset in certain period), but truely work.

Is anyone can give me another solution?

Comment: Solution 3 doesn't work for me: " parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors: details:"

Comment: I guess that is typo in solution 3, range vector selector cannot be applied to result of a query (derived value). Range vector selector always applied to raw values (timeseries stored in TSDB) hence it is sum_over_time(your_point[$__range]). However Iam not supporting this solution.

Answer (score 0):

To get the accurate total requests in a period of time, we can use `offset`:

```
http_requests_total - http_requests_total offset 24h
```

`increase` will extrapolate the range so that we can see float number in the result.

By using `offset`, the value is always integer because it just calculates the difference between start and end

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a most accurate request to gain real results from *_total countes. A bit more universal approach for fine-grained intervals is "http_requests_total - http_requests_total offset $__interval" (for grafana)

Comment: No, this is not the correct solution. If the instances are restarted, the counter will be reset. So ....