# How to use selected time range on Grafana dashboard in the panel query?

Tags: grafana

How to use selected time range on Grafana dashboard in the panel query?

The panel I am choosing is a pie chart. I set the values as seconds.
I query from my SQL database table extra data in seconds to subtract from the time range in seconds: `Grafana dashboard time range in seconds` - `my query result` should be the result.

I tried to use the answers from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47141967/how-to-use-the-selected-period-of-time-in-a-query), though it didn't help out.

Comment: Well, something like `select ($__to - $__from)/1000 as "range"` will return you time range of your dashboard in seconds. Is that what you need?

Comment: @markalex thank you, it worked, could you add it to the answers section please so that I accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get length of time range in seconds used by dashboard with the following query:

```sql
select ($__to - $__from)/1000 as "range"
```

Then you can use this expression as part of any query as usual.