# How to get total request within a time range as single scalar value in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

I want to get total number of request in a time interval as scalar values.

I have tried various solution but all give me back a time series vector. I want a single value. Does any one know how to do that.

I have tried. sum(increase(http_request_duration_ms_count[1m]))) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47138461/get-total-requests-in-a-period-of-time)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by time series vector vs. scalar. Prometheus [defines](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#expression-language-data-types) the concepts of

- instant vector, e.g. `up{instance="foo"}: (1, t1), up{instance="bar"}: (0, t1)`;
- range vectors, e.g. `up{instance="foo"}: [(1, t0), (1, t1)], up{instance="bar"}: [(0, t1), (1, t2)]`; and
- scalar, e.g. `5`.

`sum(increase(http_request_duration_ms_count[1m]))` will always produce an instant vector, i.e. the first of the above, consisting of a single time series with a single sample (as long as there exists at least one `http_request_duration_ms_count` time series).

If you want to turn that into a scalar (as defined by Prometheus) all you need to do is put a `scalar()` function call around it, i.e. `scalar(sum(increase(http_request_duration_ms_count[1m])))`.