# How to reset prometheus counter everyday at specific time?

Tags: python, prometheus

I am using prometheus_client python library.
I want to count the number of http requests came for each day.
For that I want the counter to reset at 12 AM each day. How to achieve that ?

Comment: Generally, that kind of counting would be done where you're aggregating the metrics, not at the source - maybe something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47138461/get-total-requests-in-a-period-of-time ?