Prometheus PromQL Rateinterval from midnight to now
I am currently in the process of creating a monitoring system for a Counter-Metric. An alarm is to be fired as soon as the value of an increase exceeds a threshold. I have got the panel to work (see following picture)
panel image
Expression:
increase(metric_call_total[$__range])

The next step was to create an alarm for this. Here I am faced with the problem that Grafana only allows relative time values as a range (e.g. last 1h, last 2h, last 24h, etc.).
grafana time range
However, I would need a range from 00:00 to now to be able to use the increase properly.
I have already tried to map this with promql, but without success.
Have any of you had the same problem and a solution?
Thank you very much

I tried to configure a today like range within prometheus
I tried to get the today range set up in grafana

Expected outcome:
Increase Value from 00:00 to now

Closest what I can think of at the moment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76936073/21363224.

Try the following PromQL:
increase(
  (metric_call_total and (
    floor(timestamp(metric_call_total @ end()) / (24*3600))
      == on() group_left()
    floor(vector(time() / (24*3600)))
  ))
  [1d:5m]
)

It should return metric_call_total increase for the current day starting from 00:00 UTC. You can adjust timezone offset by adding it to the time() before dividing it by (24*3600).
This query uses subquery feature for filtering out metric_call_total samples before 00:00 UTC, so they are ignored when calculating increase().
The query uses @ modifier together with end() function for calculating the timestamp() for the current day. This timestamp is then compared to the time() calculated per every 5 minutes over the last 24 hours. This filters out samples from the previous day by UTC.
The query also uses on modifier together with group_left modifier in order to match series at the left side of == with timestamp values at the right side.
The floor() function is used for rounding the division result to   Unix day.

Grafana Dashboard has this feature. You can set the time range in the selector dropdown list, which is located in the upper right corner of the dashboard.


Also, you can set it to now/d to get same result in a more dynamic way. Not sure if this is applicable to alerts, though.

Thanks for your response :) Yes for dashboards, that works like charm. But as soon as i create a alert, i am not able to use now/d or set this timerange like in the picture :(

You can set up alert condition increase(metric_call_total[$__range]) in grafana. Note that you should check if the alert rules are related to the dashboard.

Hey, thats not possible, when using unified alerting. I can only select relative time ranges :/

I checked Grafana documentation, Grafana Alerting only supports fixed relative time ranges, for example, now-1d to now
It does not support absolute time ranges or semi-relative time ranges now/d to: now.

Yes ;(,
do you know if there is a way to get this working with promql expressions?
